# Change polygon color over time by number of events in polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-joins, time, relates

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1, I have a layer of XY events with a date field, and a layer of polygons. I have spatial joined the points so that each event is associated with a polygon. I want to show the polygons using graduated colors representing the number of events within it in a given time window. Ideally, this would respond dynamically to the length of the time window - e.g., I could change the aggregation level from monthly to annual with just the corresponding time slider option, and not have to mess with the data - but I'll settle for what I can get at this point.  I've approached this from a few different angles, but they all appear to be blocked:

- Spatial joining the polygons onto the points doesn't work, because the geometry type is still Point and not Polygon.
- Calculating Frequency on the points layer by polygon-year and joining this to the original polygon layer doesn't work, because the join just picks the first row from the frequency table for each polygon.
- A relation seems to give the one-to-many polygon to polygon-time mapping I want, but it doesn't seem like you can set symbology from a relation.

I found a [blog post](https://blogs.library.duke.edu/data/2011/07/18/time-series-visualizations-in-arcgis-an-introduction/) from 2011 that does exactly what I want, but the comments are mostly people saying they're unable to reproduce it because of the enforced 1-to-1 behavior for attribute joins in ArcMap, and suggesting elaborate and unscalable workarounds. I'm using a file geodatabase, so I can't use a query table/layer.

Is it possible to achieve the behavior I want without writing a custom layer/renderer, or moving to a query layer-compatible geodatabase type?